# Laravel Cron not auto run (Windows)

Tags: laravel

I use Cron (https://github.com/liebig/cron) for Laravel 4 to run specific task in specific time

I have this code in my Global.php

```
Event::listen('cron.collectJobs', function() {
Cron::add('example1', '* * * * *', function() {
    $trip = new TripReminder();
    $trip->checkDateAndSendEmail();
});
Cron::setRunInterval(1);
$report = Cron::run();
print_r ($report);
});
```

=>This Code use to Send an email to the customers in every minute (just demo and check)

in cmd, i run this command "php artisan cron:run"

It can run well, the email was sent also, but, it only run 1 times.

I don't know what i'm missing.

Please help !

Thank you !

Comment: Just checking, you do know that you still need a crontab or online cron service provider in order to use the Cron package, right? It's not enough to call it once because it will terminate after running.

Comment: I...don't know, i just follow the tutorial, i don't even know what i'm missing :(, can you hint me ?

Comment: A crontab is a utility that lets you schedule things to run at regular intervals. It's probably a real mess getting it to run on Windows. An online cron service is something that calls a specified page for you at regular intervals. If you don't know what either is, I recommend googling for tutorials.